# Get multiple error against rejected row in Vertica

Tags: vertica

I'm using vertica for data uploading in my application. User uploads files and views data that is rejected along with the messages. The problem is, if a row contains multiple errors against multiple columns, it discards other validations and gives the error against only the first column.

Is there a way to get `;` separated error messages for each error in a row in vertica?

Comment: Could you provide a specific example? The rows loaded and the error output.

Comment: okay so, imagine there's a table that takes Name, Age, DateOfBirth with datatypes varchar, int and datetime respectively. If I load a CSV file with data `ABC, 10, 02/27/2018` it will accept no problem. If I load the file with data `ABC, xyz, 13/34/2018` it should reject this row, which it does. But the error msg that is saved against this row will only say `invalid value for age` while the value for date was also invalid.

Comment: Yes, it reports the first check that fails and doesn't run the rest to save time.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get this behavior from the loader... @mauro?

Comment: @savyuk is there a way we could manipulate this behavior so vertica can give all errors at once?